# Nginx wont update static files for Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, nginx

I have`Nginx + Gunicorn + Django` server deployed on Ubuntu. It running with `Debug=False` settings and everything works fine. `CSS` is loaded fine, `JS` works as well. But when I try to update the `css` file or `js` file, the changes I made are not reflected when I run the server.
I tried to update an old static files, also static file created after `collectstatic` command, I also tried clean `collectstatic` as well as `systemctl restart nginx (and gunicorn)`. I also cleaned my cache in browser. But when I look a page source code, these changes are not there.

this is how my `nginx config` looks like

```sh
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mediadbin.n-media.co.jp;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    access_log /home/mediaroot/mediadbin/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/mediaroot/mediadbin/logs/nginx-error.log;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static { $ I TRIED APPLY CHANGES HERE <- NOTHING happens
        alias /home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin/media;
    }

    include global404;


}
```

HERE is my `gunicorn` config

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Name of the application
NAME="mediadbin"

# Django project directory
DJANGODIR=/home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin

# how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
NUM_WORKERS=　$(( $(nproc) * 2 + 1 ))

# which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mediadbin.settings

# WSGI module name
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=mediadbin.wsgi
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
ENV=new_django
source /root/.virtualenvs/new_django/bin/activate



# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--timeout 600
--name $NAME \
--workers &NUM_WORKERS \
--bind=127.0.0.1 \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

```
>>> sudo find / -name menu_detail_look.js
/home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin/static/main_app/js/menu_detail_look.js
/home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin/main_app/static/main_app/js/menu_detail_look.js
```

↑ Updated both, nothing happens (no err in js also)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/31874223/1389057

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you set static location nginx then static files will definitely be loaded through nginx.

make you static block like (instead of alias use root):

```
location /static/ {
        root /home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin/static/;
}
```

Also make sure static root is set to: `/home/mediaroot/mediadbin/mediadbin/static/`

Running collectstatic will copy all static files to static root folder and nginx will serve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it's been so long , Aliright if now anyone working on this can check this solution

in urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

then at bottom define

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

OR  (DEPEND on your env.)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in settings.py

define media path

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Make sure to define path in /etc/nginx/sites-available/domainxxx

If your folder path is /home/admin/django/project/media

```
location /media/ {
    root /home/admin/django/project;
}
```